# split() Разбиение строки с сохранением разделителя в Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, split

Как можно разделить строку: "-33+42", с помощью регекса, с сохранением разделителей? 
Разделителями служат арифметические знаки, при чем их количество может варьироваться

Comment: что-то такое: https://www.regex101.com/r/bH6lW6/3

Comment: Можно еще проще https://www.regex101.com/r/eW6zJ5/1

Comment: он же с сохранением знаков хочет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b(?<=\d|^)(?!$)
```

Читается это так:
Граница слова `\b`
Слева от которой цифра или начало строки `(?<=\d|^)`
Справа от которой НЕ конец строки `(?!$)`

https://www.regex101.com/r/bH6lW6/8